# How to memoize a component or its result if its getting used twice on same parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, pagination, memoization

I have a parent component which is displaying files. At the top and bottom of that files section, there is a pagination component.

ParentComponent.jsx

```
export default function ParentComponent(){
    .
    .
    .
    const FilesPaginationComp = (
        <Pagination
          totalCount={totalFileCount}  //Number
          perPageCount={perPageFiles}  //Number
          currentPage={currentPage}    //Number
          changePage={setCurrentPage}  //setState function from useState hook
          offset={7}
        />
    );      
    return(
    <>
        {FilesPaginationComp}
        {files}
        {FilesPaginationComp}
    </>
    )
}
```

Pagination.jsx

```
export default function Pagination(props){
    .        //dont have any state (pure function)
    .
    .
    console.log('in pagination');   //its getting printed twice
    const paginationBtns=....
    return paginationBtns;
}
```

Since the Pagination component has the same props 2nd time, I am expecting it should not directly compute pagination values again. (print that log only once).

I have tried the below-mentioned scenarios but they didn't work for me.

1. using memo

Pagination.jsx

```
export default memo(function Pagination(props){
    .        //dont have any state (pure function)
    .
    .
    console.log('in pagination');   //its getting printed twice
    const paginationBtns=...;
    return paginationBtns;
})
```

2. memo with useMemo in pagination

Pagination.jsx

```
export default memo(function Pagination(props){
    //dont have any state (pure function)
    const paginationBtns=useMemo(()=>{
      console.log('in pagination');   //its getting printed twice
      .
      .
      .
      return final_result;
    },[...props]);
    return paginationBtns;
})
```

3. along with memo and useMemo in Pagination.jsx, useMemo in parent component

ParentComponent.jsx

```
export default function ParentComponent(){
    .
    .
    .
    const FilesPaginationComp = useMemo(()=>(
        <Pagination
            totalCount={totalFileCount}  //Number
            perPageCount={perPageFiles}  //Number
            currentPage={currentPage}    //Number
            changePage={setCurrentPage}  //setState function from useState hook
            offset={7}
        />
    ),[totalFileCount,perPageFiles,currentPage]);
    return(
    <>
        {FilesPaginationComp}
        {files}
        {FilesPaginationComp}
    </>
    )
}
```

Pagination.jsx

```
export default memo(function Pagination(props){
    //dont have any state (pure function)
    const paginationBtns=useMemo(()=>{
        console.log('in pagination');   //its getting printed twice
        .
        .
        .
        return final_result;
    },[...props]);
    return paginationBtns;
})
```

Am I missing anything or is there any other good way to achieve this?

Edit: Adding sandbox link for reference.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pagination-ymiwz

Comment: Maybe don't console log as an unintentional side-effect in the body of the function component? Try moving the console log into a `useEffect` hook and then see how many times it's actually rendered/logged. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default memo(function Pagination(props) {
    const paginationBtns=useMemo(()=>{
      console.log('in pagination');
      return final_result;
    },[...props]);
    return paginationBtns;
})
```

When `Pagination` is used twice in the parent component, two `paginationBtns` will be created because each `Pagination` will have its instance of `paginationBtns`.

You can calculate and memoize the value in the parent component and send it as props to `Pagination`.

example:

```
const Memoized = memo(({ children }) => {
  return children;
});

export default function App() {
  const expensive = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("here");
    return "hi";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Memoized children={expensive} />
      <Memoized children={expensive} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit practical-ully-p9j37]